# Define a private method after class definition

Tags: c++, function, class, private

Is there a method to define a private method after the C++ class is declared?

Why is this a good/bad practice?

Comment: `outside of "private:"` What? Why?

Comment: You declare it in `private:` section of the class. What exactly do you feel is a problem with that?

Comment: It's not possible to do it outside the `class` declaration.

Comment: the definition should be in the source and by this is kind of "private". What matters is the declaration, where there is no private "outside of private", ie you need to put the declaration after `private:`

Comment: If a function is private, only the class members (and friends) can call it. Why would want a private method, if you're not calling it from inside? Might indicate a design flaw.

Comment: @Rags how do you know that OP is not calling it in other methods?

Comment: @user463035818 It's fine to call it from other methods inside the class - that's what private is for. If it's to be called by other methods outside the class ... then it can't be private. I'm asking what the rationale is for wanting a function to be private ... but not. What the design thinking is (i.e. if that's a need, perhaps the design isn't quite right.) But I'd like to understand the thinking.

Comment: @Rags what is the rationale of having a private function? So you can use it privately but nobody else can

Comment: @user463035818 Indeed - I am familiar with private functions. OP has now edited the post indicating that what they actually want it a normal private function. Not, as was originally suggested a non-private private function (as I read it.) Normal private functions, absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the name of such declaration?

What you are looking for does not exist. Access is specified in the declaration, ie

```
struct array_list {
    private:
       void resize();
};
```

and then (without repeating the access specifier)

```
void array_list::resize() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I answered my own question. I agree with you

Comment: @CanHicabiTartanoglu if you want to answer your own question, you should do so in the answer section (nothing bad about answering your own question) not by editing the question. If you do the latter you could as well delete it (which wouldnt be particularly nice as others already put effort in helping you)

Comment: Just to note - you can have multiple private: sections in a class definition. You can flip between different access specifiers at will (I don't recommend it, but it is allowed.) So you can define all your public functions, then private functions, then public members (don't do this) then private members - or in whatever sections or orders you like. But best to keep it simple and clear.

Comment: @Rags i guess you wanted to adress this comment at OP

Comment: @user463035818 - yes, the comment was directed at OP.